# Convert an html page into a .aspx with .cs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I just bought template .Now i want to convert this HTML pages into a .aspx page with .cs with it.Does any one have any way to get through this !?but also keeping the java scripts in the html as it is .Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new `.aspx` page and copy the code from `html` file. If it contains any `javascripts` added that as a seperate file and link it

Comment: i am trying t copy the html content but its not coming up right and its a page with Image slider so there are quite a few java scripts involved ..therefore i am facing this issue from quite a long time!

Comment: if you need to keep the javascript in same page keep that in your header section and copy other things over where neccessary

Comment: +0.5 (if it existed) I partly agree with your answer. Putting the JavaScript in an external file depends on what the JavaScript is doing. If it's specific to the page, it makes more sense to leave it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

An html file won't have any code in it, so just change the extension to .aspx.

You can then manually add a .cs file, and update the controls to be asp controls as necessary.

Comment: This can sometimes create quite a headache, as the designer and cs files sometimes won't be grouped under the ASPX. I find that copying and pasting the content into a new ASPX has fewer side-effects, at least for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to just create a new page in Visual Studio, and then copy the html over. At some point your going to need to create a Web Site or Web Application depending on your needs, and that will take care of creating the correct <% Page %> declaration and code-behind. You'll likely want to put that template into a Master page really.